# logging to several files, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm very new to the log4net, and I am trying to create several files and log to them accordingly with my method calls and here is my code:

```
 private static readonly ILog firstlog = LogManager.GetLogger("Data"); private static readonly ILog secondlog = LogManager.GetLogger("General");
```

and then I log like this:

```
firstlog.Info("some message"); secondlog.Info("some message");
```

and here is my configuration file:

```
<appender name="General" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\logs\myfile1.log"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %method %-5level %logger – %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="Data" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\logs\myfile2.log"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %method %-5level %logger – %message%newline"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
<logger name="general">
  <appender-ref ref="General"/>
</logger>
<logger name="data">
  <appender-ref ref="Data"/>
</logger>
<root>
  <appender-ref ref="Data"/>
</root>
```

And they are all logged in one file and the other two files are empty. Why is this?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "they are all logged in one file" - which file is actually be written?

Comment: Just a guess but could you try to provide the exact logger name to LogManager.GetLogger in case it is case sensitive.

Comment: they are logged to file2.
yes i noticed the data and general were lower case but i'm stil getting the same thing. 
i'm thinking the root is logging to "Data" appender but both my loggers are doing nothing, i might be wrong.

Comment: actualy it worked thnx 4 d help ... nw i can log to both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the line

```
 <appender-ref ref="Data"/>
```

from the  node...

Comment: should i remove the root node, and if i remove that from all the loggers wouldn't it be the same logging to single file.

Comment: The <root> node itself should remain in the configuration. In your example, the appender "Data" is configured twice, because each logger inherits the configuration from root. If you empty the root node, you fix that.

Comment: yes it worked when i removed the appender from the root node it stopped it from logging evrything to file2. but there was another internal error that was causing this dilema i had fixed now.
thnx by d way...
god i love this site very helpful people :P